# SQL test 21 combinations if a meal exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I currently have a program that assigns meals to patients. A patient however can have a curtain diet. If the assigned meal isn't allowed due to the diet it automatically gets replaced by a replacement meal.

So database would be something like this:

- `Diet` table: Diet_id, Diet_Name
- `Replacement` table: meal_id, replacement_id, Diet_id

The thing I want to do is write a query in SQL Server to see if for every diet combination there's a replacement available.

For example:

```
A,B
A,C
A,B,C
A,B,X
A,B,C,X
A,B,...,X
```

So if diet with id 1 has no replacement for combination A,B,C I want the result to return the `meal_id` and diet combination that failed.

I currently have 21 different diets so that's fact(21) combinations. Too much to just iterate. Would there be an alternative to test all combinations?

some data:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3949922/diets.txt

Comment: It would help if you gave some sample data from tables Diet and Replacement

Answer (score 1):

To just get the ID's:

```
Select diet_id from Diet
except
Select diet_id from Replacement
```

Comment: That wouldn't check for combitations. only if there is a replacement for that diet. i don't only need to check if the diet exists. But i also need to know if someone who has diet A and B if he gets a replacement. For this to happen i need a replacement that has both A and B as diet.